# ASUS N751JK, bluetooth doesn't work, ubuntu 17.10

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10, asus

`rfkill list` output is normal:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`hciconfig -a` gives the following info

```
hci0:    Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 9C:D2:1E:0D:2F:B2  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 128:2
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:1160 acl:0 sco:0 events:62 errors:0
    TX bytes:742 acl:0 sco:0 commands:62 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

Typping of `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` results in:

```
Can't init device hci0: Invalid request code (56)
```

The output of `hcitool dev` command is empty:

```
Devices:
```

This is `hcitool scan` output

```
Device is not available: No such device
```

I seached for similar problems, checked their solutions if it works in my case, but failed - nothing has helped me. So I've decided to ask it here

There may be another usefull information which is not given here for now. But I don't know yet what should be provided in order to make the problem be solved easier.

Just in case, (1)`lsusb` and (2)`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` outputs are attached below:

(1)

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3fd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e8d:763f MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

(2)

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn 
Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless 
Network Adapter [105b:e074]
Kernel driver in use: mt7630e
Kernel modules: wl, mt7630e
```

Comment: Hi, did  you find a solution? I tried also following https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/wiki/Get-bluetooth-working-in-Linux-kernel--with-mt7630e
but had no luck...